# How do fixed point bit values in swf files work?

Tags: matrix, flash, fixed, point, bit

The SWF File Format Specification Version 19 says the scale value in the MATRIX record is stored as FB, somewhere else in the specification it says the FB is a 32 bit 16.16 fixed point value, but there's a value how many bits it uses to store the value and in the example it is a 3.16 value and not a 16.16 value.

- How can it be a 32 bit 16.16 value and a 19 bit 3.16 value at the same time?
- How does Flash Player know wheter it's a 3.16, 4.15, 5.14, X.X value?
- What exactly is the format of the FB?

I want to know this because I want to insert a sprite into a already compiled SWF file. I already succesfully used the PlaceObject tag once in that sprite but now I have an image that has to be scaled down, this is done in the MATRIX record too, but first I didn't need the FB because the other image already is at the right scale.

edit:
I'm going to try if I can make new sprites with Sothink SWF Quicker tomorrow, if it doesn't work I'll try to make a simple swf file with the sprite in it using Adobe Flash CS 6 and then copy the DefineSprite tag into the other SWF file. If someone answers I'll first try to do the scale thing with a hex editor before I try it with Sothink SWF Quicker.

edit2:
Sothink SWF Quicker crashes when I try to Import the SWF file. If copying the tag from the SWF file I'm going to create doesn't work I'll delete the image I want to place with the PlaceObject tag and then reinsert it scaled down.

edit3:
I don't know how to make Flash use the DefineSprite tag, so I added a DefineBitsLossless2 tag with the image scaled down, I'll be using this image in the sprite. I don't need the FB now anymore, but it still would be nice to know how they work, so if someone know it, please answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix record begins like this:

```
HasScale    UB[1]
NScaleBits  If HasScale=1, UB[5]
ScaleX      If HasScale=1, FB[NScaleBits]
ScaleY      If HasScale=1, FB[NScaleBits]
...
```

FB[NScaleBits] is indeed a fixed-point value, but not necessarily 16.16 - it all comes down to NScaleBits (so it's different from the regular fixed-point number, which is always 16.16).

The number of bits used is fixed or specified beforehand, like in case with Matrix, so Flash Player *just knows*.

For instance, 2.8 would be if 0x28000 in dex, and NScaleBits is 19 in this case, because we need minimum of 3 bits to represebt signed number "2" (3 + 16 = 19).

I know this is an old question.
Still, someone might stumble upon it, the way I did.

Comment: I figured out how it works a long time ago, but I accepted it anyway, because it is a good answer.